# DataNode not started after changing the datanode directories parameter. DiskErrorException

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I have added the new disk to the hortonworks sandbox on the OracleVM, following this example:

https://muffinresearch.co.uk/adding-more-disk-space-to-a-linux-virtual-machine/

I set the owner of the mounted disk directory as hdfs:hadoop recursively and give the 777 permisions to it.

I added the mounted disk folder to the datanode directories after coma using Ambari. Also tried changing XML directly.

And after the restart the dataNode always crashes with the DiskErrorException Too many failed volumes.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround of this problem, I mounted the disk to the to the /mnt/sdb folder,
and this folder I use as the datanode directories entry. But if create the /mnt/sdb/data and use it as entry the exception dissapears and everythig works like a charm.

No idea why(